# Vaadin 14: Is it possible to call ui.navigate() from within a background thread ui.access()

Tags: multithreading, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 14 app that shows a processing indicator view (@Push ProcessingView) to the user whilst doing some long (several seconds) worth of processing in a background thread. When the background thread is finished I call ui.navigate() to another view (CompleteView) from within a ui.access() block. The ui object is passed to the background thread, I do not use UI.getCurrent() in the thread.

However, randomly and unpredictably, some sessions end up in an infinite loop of refreshing the ProcessingView and generating infinite threads. No exceptions are thrown, and no errors reported, the Javascript console just reports that the session stopped unexpectedly and performs a refresh.

I suspect a bug in Vaadin that is causing the session to fail.

Is it supported in Vaadin 14 that ui.navigate() can be called from a ui.access() background thread or is only updating components onscreen supported?

Any other ideas why this would happen?

Thx for any pointers.

Comment: Even if it works, isn't that annoying for the user to randomly get
transfered somewhere else?  So even if it's a bug or undefined
behaviour, I am not surprised it took so long to find such a problem.

Comment: Could you share code that describes how you have implemented it. I tried similar thing myself and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for trying. My code is unfortunately complex and highly integrated - its not a simple test case. I just got similar behavior during development at a different point in the flow and this time got the following error in my log files:

'2021-07-09 10:52:27,661 WARN  [com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler] (default task-1) Resynchronizing UI by client's request. Under normal operations this should not happen and may indicate a bug in Vaadin platform. If you see this message regularly please open a bug report at https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues'

Comment: I suspect this is the same bug as https://github.com/vaadin/multiplatform-runtime/issues/86

Comment: The issue Franz linked says that the fix was going to be released in Vaadin 14.6.6, have you tested whether that solves the problem for you?

Comment: I never get the issue in test, only in production. I released the fixed vaadin version but still got 2 cases of the problem in the logs.

Because the issue comments seem to indicate that the error only occurs in the first rendering, I now launch the background thread from a javascipt @ClientCallable and execute the javascript from onAttach. The idea is to try and delay the xall till after first rendering. So far si good, but its only been in production for 2 days.